# RGBDSlam Point Cloud Scaling

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to display the data collected by RGBDSlam as a .ply file on a separate program (web GUI by XB PointStream). The problem is that when this file is displayed on the GUI, it comes out very tiny and all the points look very close together. Is there a way to scale up the size of the point cloud data so that it displays correctly on XB PointStream?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55812/rgbdslam-point-cloud-scaling/) by [nikkihohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4243/nikkihohn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-20**:
Do you have a link to look at the cloud? Maybe you can use meshlab to modify the .ply file. (BTW: Correct tagging is crucial on this site)

**Comment by [nikkihohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4243/nikkihohn/) on 2013-02-23**:
I want to process the point cloud automatically, because I will be processing a lot of clouds. Does meshlab have a way to run a script or something to automatically resize a point cloud?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-24**:
I don't know whether meshlab can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If scaling is all you need, since the ply format is very simple, you could just write a script (e.g. in python) to rescale your cloud, by parsing in the ply and multiplying the coordinates by a factor.

Alternatively you could alter RGBDSLAM to do so. The ply file is written from `src/graph_mgr_io.cpp` line 430. You could just add the scalling factor in lines 460-462.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nikkihohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4243/nikkihohn/) on 2013-02-24**:
Felix, thanks for your help. I was able to figure it out and the map looks great now. One thing though, the file's path was src/graph_manager.cpp (lines 1361-1363).

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-25**:
You're welcome. You may be using an older version, I've split the file recently.